# Google In App Billing v3 Handle Cancel Managed Product

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing

My app has allows user purchases an item, it will be tracked on my server and, finally consumed, so the user can purchase again the same item.

I am using this [IAB SDK](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) to handle IAB. However, I am having a hard time checking the status of the purchase of a managed consumable product (not subscription). I need to know whether or not the payment got cancelled for any reason. Noted: the product is not yet consumed.

There is a section explaining **handle canceled subscriptions** but not for managed products.

I have tried calling `loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle` and `getPurchaseTransactionDetails(PRODUCT_ID).purchaseInfo.purchaseData.purchaseState` The state is always successful even I already cancelled the order in the Google Payment Center.
Then if I want to consume this already-cancelled order, it'll give me item not owned error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional testing, I discovered it might just take some time for the client to get the updated status on the transaction.

I tried calling `bp.isPurchased(PRODUCT_ID);` again and got it returned `false`. It might not be real time report, but better than nothing.